# Checking unique enteries and Removing Duplicates in pandas dataframe of user id interactions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe which looks like this:

user_id : Represents user

question_id : Represent question number

user_answer : which option user has opted for the specific question from (A,B,C,D)

correct_answer: What is correct answer for that specific question

correct : if 0.0 it means users answer was not right , if 1.0 it means user answer is right

elapsed_time : it represents time in minutes user took to answer that question

| user_iD | question_id | user_answer | correct answer | correct | elapsed_time | solving_id | bundle_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | D | 0.0 | 5.00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | B | D | 0.0 | 3.00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | D | D | 1.0 | 7.00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | C | B | 0.0 | 5.00 | 10 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 | B | B | 1.0 | 15.0 | 10 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 | B | B | 1.0 | 2.00 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | 25 | C | A | 0.0 | 5.00 | 25 | 7 |
| 3 | 25 | A | A | 1.0 | 1.00 | 25 | 7 |

**What I want another dataframe to look like is this**

| user_iD | question_id | user_answer | correct answer | correct | elapsed_time | solving_id | bundle_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | D | D | 1.0 | 7.00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | B | B | 1.0 | 15.0 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | 25 | A | A | 1.0 | 1.00 | 25 | 7 |

It should remove the duplicate questions attempted by a user and keeps the one which user corrected the very first time.

**What I have done so far , this gives me an error**

```
df = df['correct'].eq(1) & ~df.drop_duplicated(['user_iD','question_id','correct'])
```

**ERROR :** AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicated'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`Groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [174]: ix = df[df.correct.eq(1)].groupby(['user_iD', 'question_id'])['elapsed_time'].idxmax()

In [175]: df.loc[ix]
Out[175]: 
   user_iD  question_id user_answer correct answer  correct  elapsed_time  solving_id  bundle_id
2        1            1           D              D      1.0           7.0           1          1
4        2           10           B              B      1.0          15.0          10          5
7        3           25           A              A      1.0           1.0          25          7
```

Answer (score 2):

For your boolean mask, you need `duplicated` instead of `drop_duplicated`. So instead of

```
df['correct'].eq(1) & ~df.drop_duplicated(['user_iD','question_id','correct'])
```

you want

```
mask = df['correct'].eq(1) & ~df.duplicated(['user_iD','question_id','correct'])
```

This will give you a boolean mask. Then your desired outcome is obtained using this mask on `df`:

```
out = df[mask]
```

You can get the same outcome by filtering for `correct` first and then using `drop_duplicates` method:

```
out = df[df['correct']==1].drop_duplicates('correct answer'))
```

Output:

```
   user_iD  question_id user_answer correct answer  correct  elapsed_time  \
2        1            1           D              D      1.0           7.0   
4        2           10           B              B      1.0          15.0   
7        3           25           A              A      1.0           1.0   

   solving_id  bundle_id  
2           1          1  
4          10          5  
7          25          7
```

Comment: honestly I think this is best solution here.

Answer (score 1):

`drop_duplicated` wrong typo. use [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Also, check `keep` parameter to preserve row you want.

Answer (score 1):

groupby and agg are good at conditionally isolating. In this case, filter the ones and find the max in each group of the user_iD

```
df[df['correct'].eq(1.0)].groupby(df['user_iD']).agg('max')

         
                  user_iD  question_id user_answer correct answer  

correct  \
user_iD                                                             
1              1            1           D              D      1.0   
2              2           10           B              B      1.0   
3              3           25           A              A      1.0   

         elapsed_time  solving_id  bundle_id  
user_iD                                       
1                 7.0           1          1  
2                15.0          10          5  
3                 1.0          25          7
```